# How to set date from React Date Picker with Google Chrome Dev tool?

Tags: html, reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker, google-developer-tools

I have a problem
I would like to set date to website (as picture below)
with react-date-picker
I want to know code for set date with google chrome dev tool
Please help and find solution or recommend for me krub
[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA3UX.png)

Ps. That Date-picker can't set text, click to select date only

Change date with code from google chrome dev tool